Program.cs file after ASP.NET Core 6
I wrote a simple token generating API with ASP.NET Core 6. I need to do an integration test. When I write the integration test, it needs to reference the Program class, but I get an error

The ‘Program’ element is inaccessible due to the protection level

So after adding namespace and public, I get an error

CS0017: More than one entry point is defined in the program. Specify /main to specify the type containing the entry point.

I cannot solve it.
This is my Program.cs:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System.Text;
using TokenProject.Model;


var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// CORS yapılandırması
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("AllowAngularApp",
                    builder =>
                    {
                        builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200") // Angular uygulamasının adresi
                               .AllowAnyHeader()
                               .AllowAnyMethod()
                               .AllowCredentials(); // Credentials ekledim
                    });
            });

// JWT kimlik doğrulama yapılandırması
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
           {
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            }).AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
                {
                    OnAuthenticationFailed = context =>
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Token validation failed: " + context.Exception.Message);
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    },
                    OnTokenValidated = context =>
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Token validated: " + context.SecurityToken);
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    }
                };
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidateAudience = true,
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
                    ValidAudience = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Audience"],
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.Configuration["Jwt:Key"]))
                };
            });

builder.Services.AddDbContext<TokenDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("TokenDB")));

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

// CORS politikasını kullan
app.UseCors("AllowAngularApp");

// Authentication ve Authorization'ı kullan
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();

TokenControllerTests:
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Xunit;

namespace Token.IntegrationTests
{
    public class TokenControllerTests : IClassFixture<WebApplicationFactory<Program>>
    {
        private readonly HttpClient _client;

        public TokenControllerTests(WebApplicationFactory<Program> factory)
        {
            _client = factory.CreateClient();
        }
        
        [Fact]
        public async Task Get_Token_Endpoint_Returns_Success()
        {
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "/api/token");
            var response = await _client.SendAsync(request);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        }

        [Fact]
        public async Task Post_Token_Returns_Success()
        {
            
            var tokenRequest = new
            {
                Username = "testuser",
                Password = "P@ssw0rd"
            };

            var content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tokenRequest), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            
            var response = await _client.PostAsync("http://localhost:7125/api/Auth/login", content);
            
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        }
    }
}


Add the following code to the end of your Program.cs( that is to say add the code after app.Run();):
app.Run();  
public partial class Program { }

